# Cannot boot Gparted (or any other USB/CD) on a Dell Vostro 200

Tags: macos

Very strange problem.  Trying to get Leopard installed on a Dell Vostro 200 Minitower but can't get past Step Zero.  Didn't boot of a formatted USB key, so I burned a Gparted ISO and tweaked the BIOS appropriately but get

Boot from CD : [I hit enter]
No boot device available.  Press ENTER key to retry
SATA-0: Installed
SATA-1: Installed
SATA-4: None
SATA-5: None

[ENTER, same thing].

Any ideas?  I upgraded the Dell Bios to the latest one but no help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried these boot CDs and USB flash disks on another machine where they did work?

I had a problem specifically with syslinux, which is the part that makes USB flash disks bootable, where the defaults worked on everything but one motherboard (an ATi Xpress200 one). The fix was to specify the option for a smaller boot partition. This was very frustrating trial and error. However I never had a problem with a CD, they would either work everywhere or no-where, assuming booting off CD was an option at all, which you're saying it is.

Comment: it's quite possible a bad burn is preventing a boot from CD.  if you haven't verified with another system that the CD boots, check that, or try burning another disc.  (tip: burn slow to make sure you get a good burn.)